# Robot Framework how to set file path?

Tags: robotframework

I am using **Choose File** keyword to upload file. In documentation is written that I can use **${CURDIR}** to set the path to my file, but it means that this file has to be in the same directory **${CURDIR}**/filename.txt. But how to set the path to the file that exists in another directory?

Comment: By the way, you can set a specific path or use../ to go back to your target directory

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you don't want to use `${CURDIR}`, you don't have to. You can use any path you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **${EXECDIR}** so you go back to the root and go from there.